# Cypress Route to Modify URL and pass certain Parameters

Tags: cypress

```
// Stub a response to PUT comments/ ****
 cy.route({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'comments/*',
  status: 404,
  response: { error: message },
  delay: 500,
}).as('putComment')

// we have code that puts a comment when
// the button is clicked in scripts.js
cy.get('.network-put').click()


cy.wait('@putComment')
```

Above code is just the sample example.
In above example, I want to modify the URL once user click on Put button. If user click on PUT button, */comment gets called. However, I want to STUB it through Cypress. I want below URL is /comment?isreusable = true. Base URL till comment is same. To this URL, I want to pass isreusable = true as query string parameters.

Real Example - License Team has provided us certain licenses. We are using it in our test automaton suite. Once we consume license , ther is NO way to return it or reuse it. Now how we can execute our automation suite ? Therefore, development team has exposed endpoint. This endpoint is not available on U> If use clicks on consume button on UI, below endpoint gets called

```
**/api/activations
```

Now I want to call **/api/activations ? ignoreError=true so that all the errors will be ignored and license will get consumed. Is there exists a a way in Cypress ?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: In the new Cypress release, they made several enhancements for route(). We have implemented this in our projects. However, modifying URL is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using cy.intercept()  and req.continue()

```
cy.intercept(
        {url: '/api/activations', middleware: true},
        (req) => {
             req.url = req.url + '?ignoreError=true'; // modify original url
             // Continue the request without stubbing
             req.continue((res)=>{
                console.log("RESPONSE ", res) // Print response if required
             });
        })
})
```